# Active Directory User Can be Found in VM but not in Host

Tags: c#

I have a VM installed Windows Server 2012 and has AD server on it. I tried following code in VM and it works but when I tried the same code at host it just can't work.

Here's my code:

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "tryad.com");

if (principalContext != null)
{
    UserPrincipal userP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "sky@tryad.com");

    if (userP != null)
    {
        if (principalContext.ValidateCredentials("sky@tryad.com", "!QAZ2wsx"))
        {
            userP.ChangePassword("!QAZ2wsx", "#EDC4rfv");
            userP.Save();

            if (principalContext.ValidateCredentials("sky@tryad.com", "#EDC4rfv"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Success.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my VM it work just fine. But when in my host, it will have exception at `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "sky@tryad.com");`
and the message is:

> User account or password is not correct.

The only difference is I use `"tryad.com"` as domain in VM, and use `"192.168.XXX.XXX"` in host. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: The domain for the host is not valid domain. [reference](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/Active-Directory-domain-AD-domain)

You have to still input a valid domain for the service to work.

Comment: But I tried "tryad.com" at host, and I can't connect to the server. By the way, I'm using host-only network mode on VM.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved this by changing

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "tryad.com");
```

to

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.xxx.xxx", "DC=TryAD,DC=COM", username, password);
```

Then it works!
But I have no idea how this work.
Does anybody know?

Comment: What happens if you ping tryad.com from your host? Have you set up all required connectivity so that the host can see inside the VM?

Comment: "Can't find DNS" when I ping tryad.com at host, but I can remote VM by IP

Comment: OK so you need `PING tryad.com` to resolve properly in order to use `tryad.com`. The "brute force" method is to add an entry to your hosts file on your host. But if this is an exercise in learning, you should learn about setting up DNS.